# HashSet for finding duplicate arrays

Tags: java, arraylist, set, duplicates, hashset

I am new to HashSets. How should I change this code in order to print 3? are there better methods than hashset? Like is BST better than HashSet for this problem?

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FindDuplicates {
    //finding duplicates in array1 and array2 using hashset and putting them into a list
    public ArrayList<Integer> findDuplicates(ArrayList<Integer> list1, ArrayList<Integer> list2){
        ArrayList<Integer> duplicateList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Set<Object> listTemp=new HashSet<>();
        if (list1.size() < list2.size()){
            listTemp.add(list1);
            for (int i=0; i<list2.size();i++){
                if (listTemp.contains(list2.get(i)))
                    duplicateList.add(list2.get(i));
            }
        }
        else {
            listTemp.add(list2);
            for (int i=0; i<list1.size();i++){
                if (listTemp.contains(list1.get(i)))
                    duplicateList.add(list1.get(i));
            }
        }

        return duplicateList;
    }

    public static void main(String argc[]){
        FindDuplicates fd= new FindDuplicates();
        ArrayList<Integer> l1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> l2=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        l1.add(3);
        l1.add(1);
        l1.add(5);
        l2.add(3);
        System.out.print(fd.findDuplicates(l1, l2));

    }
}
```

Comment: Are those arrays consisting only of unique numbers? I mean, can one array contain two "ones" for example?

Comment: well, that is a good question, I am getting started to learn about hashset , so TBH it won't differ for me but possibly would differ for Set data structure right?

Comment: Well set can only contain each number once (it contains a number or not). Array can have the same number multiple times. It's only the matter of defining what difference you want to return here in case you have [1,1] and [1,2] for example :-) But assuming you don't have duplicates in your lists Mureinik's answer is great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simplify this method considerably by using the [`retainAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-) method:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> findDuplicates
    (ArrayList<Integer> list1, ArrayList<Integer> list2) {

    Set<Integer> duplicates = new HashSet<>(list1);
    duplicates.retainAll(new HashSet<>(list2));
    return new ArrayList<>(duplicates);
}
```

Comment: Would you use the same method if one of the lists was significantly larger than the other one? Or the same data structure? I am curious if BST would be a better choice or Set in that case?

Comment: You should avoid using `retainAll` with an `ArrayList` argument as `contains` is `O(n)`, resulting in terrible performance. I'd use a `HashSet` for both.

Comment: @PaulBoddington what's the solution then?

Comment: This is the solution. I'd just do `duplicates.retainAll(new HashSet<>(list2));` instead. For small lists it doesn't matter, but for lists with millions of elements, `retainAll` can easily take literally minutes. Jon Skeet wrote a blog post about `containsAll`, `removeAll` and `retainAll` (I can't find the link right now). Basically don't pass an `ArrayList` to these methods.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and clarifications :)